# PHP Dynamic page include

Tags: php, url, dynamic, include

I have an simple PHP script that includes a file, when it's requested via URL.

for an example: http://example.com/index.php?page=about
So this includes the page about.inc

This is working, but i have another problem. When someone visits the homepage so just:
http://example.com/ . It will show me this

```
Undefined index: beta in /home/admin/domains/mydomainname.nl/public_html/index.php on line 3
```

That is:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
```

I know I can disable the error notice in PHP, but this is not a solution but a workaround.

```
$path = 'app/inc/pages/dynamic/';
$page = $_GET['page'];
$php  = '.inc';
$both = $path . $page . $php;
$pages = array('index', 'home', 'about', 'contact');
if (!empty($page)) {

    if(in_array($page,$pages)) {
        //$page .= '.php';
        include($both);
    }
    else {
    include('app/inc/pages/dynamic/404.inc');
    }
}
else {
    include('app/inc/pages/dynamic/home.inc');
}
}
```

It does include the homepage via

```
else {
    include('app/inc/pages/dynamic/home.inc');
}
```

My question is how to solve this?

Comment: Check isset($_GET['page'])

Comment: where are you using $beta??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: replace 3 no line by this:

```
  $page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : '';
```

It will set empty in the `$page` variable if no page is provided. You have double `$` in $path. 
Full code:

```
$path = 'app/inc/pages/dynamic/';
$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : '' ;
$php  = '.inc';
$both = $path . $page . $php;
$pages = array('index', 'home', 'about', 'contact');
if (!empty($page)) {

    if(in_array($page,$pages)) {
        //$page .= '.php';
        include($both);
    }
    else {
        include('app/inc/pages/dynamic/404.inc');
    }
}
else {
    include('app/inc/pages/dynamic/home.inc');
}
```

Comment: @Fadi Abdalkhalk: If it worked please Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.It will be a green mark if it is accepted correctly